# ASP.net connect to MySql without installing DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I just want to be able to connect to a remote MySQL database on my ASP.net c# website running on localhost.

It's so I can grab some records, and insert them into my SQL server database.  Do I need to download any drivers?  And how do I connect and fetch records?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [ADO.Net driver for MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/). This will allow you to connect to a MySQL database and use all of the .Net ADO standard stuff to get your data and put it elsewhere.

The added benefit about using the ADO.Net driver is that you can easily use the same data objects (DataTable, DataRow, etc.) when inserting the data into SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded and installed it, but `using MySql.Data;` gives red squiggle.  Do I need to add a reference or DLL or something?

Comment: Ah added the DLL's manually with reference now, working, thanks!